# Minutely cron job is not running

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

I added the line

```
*/1 * * * * /home/zach/test.sh
```

to my crontab, where the contents of `/home/zach/test.sh` are as follows:

```
touch /home/zach/test.txt
```

Yet, no file `test.txt` is being created in that folder. Is there any reason why cron wouldn't be performing the desired job?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In order to answer your question, please provide more information (**edit** your question). 1) Did you mark the `/home/zach/test.sh` script executable? (provide the output of `ls -l /home/zach/test.sh`) 2) Do you have the shebang in the script? (I don't see it in your question) 3) How exactly did you add it to your crontab? (`crontab -e`?)

Answer (score 1):

First, your `test.sh` file should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /home/zach/test.txt
```

if you want it to be a bash script.

Second, be sure that this script has permissions of executing. To do so, run this command in terminal:

```
chmod +x /home/zach/test.sh
```

Third, be sure that you have permission to create new files in `/home/zach`.

Fourth, add your new cron job using `crontab -e` command.

Answer (score 0):

try `* * * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/zach/test.sh`

Comment: January is right, /1 is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

The `/1` is unnecessary. Just do

```
* * * * * /home/zach/test.sh
```

EDIT: I wrote "In fact, I think that `/N` means "skip every N-th instance", and in that case will result in skipping *every* instance. " This is not true, it means "every N-th instance". Therefore both variants work. Therefore, I will remove my answer. I think you have a permissions problem. Why not try

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /tmp/blah
```

Answer (score 0):

If your script is still not executed, you can refer at http://www.tcpdump.com/kb/os/linux/linux-cron-tutorial.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.